Удалить все теги в подзаголовках <h2>...</h2> и <h3>....</h3>
Необходимо удалить с помощью регулярных выражений (на PHP) все теги, которые встречаются в подзаголовках между тегами <h2>...</h2> и <h3>....</h3>.
Пример текста:
<p>слово1 слово2</p>
<h2>Какой-то <strong>подзаголовок <i class="red">второго</i></strong> уровня
</h2>
<h3><u id="green">Другой <b>подзаголовок</b> третьего</ul> уровня </h3>
<p>текст</p>

На выходе получить:
<p>слово1 слово2</p>
<h2>Какой-то подзаголовок второго уровня
</h2>
<h3>Другой подзаголовок третьего уровня </h3>
<p>текст</p>


Где ваше решение, с которым у вас не получается решить вопрос?

@DanielProtopopov строго говоря, этот вопрос вступает в противоречие с целями этого сайта (правда только в том случае, если ответа на такой вопрос ещё не давали).


Необходимо удалить с помощью регулярных выражений (на PHP) все теги, которые встречаются в подзаголовках между тегами h2 и h3

Не знаю есть ли в ПХП рекурсивность в применении регулярки... Но в JS ее нет.
Проблему ТС можно решить вот так.


let t = `<p>слово1 слово2</p>
<h2>Какой-то <strong>подзаголовок <i class="red">второго</i></strong> уровня
</h2>
<h3><ul id="green">Другой <b>подзаголовок</b> третьего</ul> уровня </h3>
<p>текст</p>`
const r = /(?<=<h\d.+?)<(\S+).*?>(.+?)<\/\1>/g
const rt = /<(h\d).+?<(?=.+?<\/\1)/
while (rt.test(t)) {
    t = t.replace(r, '$2')
}
console.log(t)




Извиняюсь, а при чём тут js?

@Ипатьев, регулярка - она и в Африке регулярка...

@ksa, но ведь в ответе не регулярка...

Если не принципиально удалить сразу одним регулярным выражением,то можно сделать вот так:
<?php
$str = '<p>слово1 слово2</p>
<h2>Какой-то <strong>подзаголовок <i class="red">второго</i></strong> уровня</h2>
<h3><u id="green">Другой <b>подзаголовок</b> третьего</ul> уровня </h3>
<p>текст</p>';

echo "BEFORE:\n===\n".$str."\n===\n";
preg_match_all("/<h(2|3)>(.*?)<\/h(2|3)>/imu", $str, $matches);
if ( is_array( $matches ) && count( $matches ) > 2 && is_array($matches[2]) && count( $matches[2]) > 0 ) {
    foreach( $matches[2] as $m ) {
        $str = preg_replace("/".preg_quote($m, "/")."/imu", strip_tags( $m ), $str );
    }
}
echo "AFTER:\n===\n".$str."\n===\n";

Результат:
BEFORE:
===
<p>слово1 слово2</p>
<h2>Какой-то <strong>подзаголовок <i class="red">второго</i></strong> уровня</h2>
<h3><u id="green">Другой <b>подзаголовок</b> третьего</ul> уровня </h3>
<p>текст</p>
===
AFTER:
===
<p>слово1 слово2</p>
<h2>Какой-то подзаголовок второго уровня</h2>
<h3>Другой подзаголовок третьего уровня </h3>
<p>текст</p>
===


А если принципиально то можно и одной.

Приблизительно так (можно лучше, но надо химичить): tio.run
<?php

$s = '<p>слово1 слово2</p>
<h2>Какой-то <strong>подзаголовок <i class="red">второго</i></strong> уровня
</h2>
<h3><u id="green">Другой <b>подзаголовок</b> третьего</ul> уровня </h3>
<p>текст</p>';

print preg_replace('~</?(?!h\d\b)\w+\b[^>]*>(?=((?!<h\d\b).)*</h\d>)~mis', '', $s);

